# Python - Lists and Sorting

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
def dictionary():
    ''' pulls the usernames and passwords from testdata.txt '''
    global passwords, usernames
    usernames = []
    passwords = []

    file_open = open('testdata.txt', 'r')

    for accounts in file_open:

        username, password = accounts.split('\t')
        password = password.strip('\n')

        usernames.append(username)
        passwords.append(password)

def output():
    ''' outputs the header for the list and computes a portion of the equations to output '''
    password_data_list = []
    password_frequency_total = 0
    amount = 0

    for password in passwords:
        password_frequency_total = password_frequency_total + 1

    print('{:<10}{:>17}{:>13}'.format('Password', 'Frequency', '%'))
    print('=' * 40)

    for password in passwords:
        password_frequency = passwords.count(password)
        password_frequency_percentage = ((password_frequency / password_frequency_total) * 100)
        password_data = '{:<10}{:>17}{:>12.4f}%'.format(password, password_frequency, password_frequency_percentage)
        password_data_list.append(password_data)

    for x in password_data_list:
        print(x)
```

[image]
Q. How do I get the frequency sorted from biggest to smallest number?

Comment: Aside: are those statistics accurate, there's duplicate entries with same percentage values.

Answer (score 0):

First for all: always use the `with` statement to handle files. This secure the correctly file close when you exit of the `with` conext, e.g.:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for foo in file:
        # do whatever
```

For you problem: you can use `sort()` method in arrays to, well, sort thems. In your case, yo can do `password_data_list.sort()` and done.

Comment: I'm trying to get the frequency from biggest to smallest, where would you suggest I put sort() to receive that output?

Comment: Just in the line before of the `for x in password_data_list: ...` in you `output` fuction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the frequency of each password efficiently as a dict of password-to-count mapping, which you can use as a key to sort the passwords. Using a loop to count `password_frequency_total` is unnecessary because you simply use the length of the `passwords` list instead:

```
from collections import Counter
password_frequency = Counter(passwords)

print('{:<10}{:>17}{:>13}'.format('Password', 'Frequency', '%'))
print('=' * 40)

for password in sorted(passwords, key=password_frequency.get):
    password_frequency_percentage = ((password_frequency[password] / len(passwords)) * 100)
    password_data = '{:<10}{:>17}{:>12.4f}%'.format(password, password_frequency, password_frequency_percentage)
    password_data_list.append(password_data)
```